# Como carregar uma tabela usando ajax do datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando carregar uma tabela usando o componente [datatables](http://datatables.net/).

O retorno desta requisição ajax é um objeto json neste formato:

```
data = {
  "CLIENTES": {
    "0": {
      "ID": "1",
      "NOME": 'GABRIEL'
    },
    "1": {
      "ID": "2",
      "NOME": 'RODRIGUES'
    }
  }
}
```

Na documentação [columns data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#string) é citado que devem ser criada a seguinte estrutura:

```
table.DataTable({
  "ajax": url,
  columns: [
    {"data": "CLIENTES.ID"},
    {"data": "CLIENTES.NOME"}
  ]
});
```

Mas  não é realizado o acesso corretamente aos índices, neste caso  deveriam ser acessados:

```
{"data": "CLIENTES['0'].ID"},
{"data": "CLIENTES['1'].ID"},
```

Dinamicamente, como eu poderia fazer isto ?

Existe uma pergunta relacionada que também não solucionou minha dúvida: [Carregar tabela com json usando datatables](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68697/carregar-tabela-com-json-usando-datatables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas recriei o array removendo CLIENTES usando a função `$.map`.

**Solução:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    data = {
      "CLIENTES": {
        "0": {
           "ID": "1",
           "NOME": 'GABRIEL'
        },
       "1": {
           "ID": "2",
           "NOME": 'RODRIGUES'
         }
       }
     };


   var newData = $.map(data.CLIENTES, function(el) { return el });

   $('#example').DataTable({
       data: newData,
       columns: [
       {"data": "ID"},
       {"data": "NOME"}
       ]
    });

});
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/pf9dv6d4/)